# "colorful comment" option is a big fraud

Tags: discussion, unicoins

i bought the colorful comment option with my hard earned unicoins because i thought the comments get more personality as promised.
But all comments are colored equally. no sign of personality just uniformity.

That is a big fraud!!1!!one!eleven

Comment: That's the unicorn way, get your hearth into the rainbow!

Comment: Can you include a screenshot?

Comment: *not so uniform now, eh?*

Comment: **i want more**

Comment: **But i see colorful !**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, it's your eyes that are a big fraud. The comments appear in rainbow colors to unicorns, but to humans they just appear to be the same color. I've spent many long days and nights searching for a solution, and I found this:

[image]

For only 20 unicoins, you can buy these glasses that will allow you to see the comments in color. They are handcrafted by artesian unicorns up in the snowy mountains. Enjoy!

Comment: Its still fraud as we aint unicorns.

Comment: _Some of us might be unicorns..._

Comment: @MiharuDante it's only a fraud if you can prove it to be and since you're not a unicorn you can't prove it wrong.

Comment: Maybe they get a different color if you mention unicorns or unicoins?

Comment: I hope this comment will appear pretty.

Comment: So, by the `«Made in China»` inscription, we can guess that the snowy mountains where unicorns live are in China.

Comment: It sucks to be a half unicorn. Some of the comments are colored and some are not.

Answer (score 9):

They do have personality. It would simply seem that the personalities of the comments in your batch were conformist.

Comment: Ha! Here, have all my unicoins.

Answer (score 3):

Remember to put on your [rose colored glasses](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rose-coloured+glasses), before trying to view this add-on.

[image]