# Why unicorn glasses are not being sold?

Tags: discussion, unicorns

I found the fact some of the users that have no power to acquire the glasses should have a chance to see their unique comments in rainbow colours.

So Stack Overflow should make an effort to contact the glasses Artisan and make it available on the buy options.

More details on the glasses can be found at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227506/148364

Comment: Your first title (*Unicron* glasses) was better.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi unhappily that was a typo and the actual glasses name is unknown to my knowledge as of the moment.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi how do you make it pink?...html?

Comment: @AnkitSharma, I did not do anything, that pink in on your side :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi you all text is appearing blue except unicorn word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not buy the premium unicorn outfit instead of the glasses? The suit has the functionality of the glasses built in already! All the features are:

- See the world in full rainbow colours.
- You smell like flowers
- Your farts will be changed to lavender parfume

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

The fact that those glasses aren't sold is because they're to epic for a normal user. You also need a lot of unicoins to buy this.

However, you can find these glasses for free at the rainbow valleys where the unicorns live. But be carefully! The unicorns can be very aggressive to normal users.

[image: rainbow valley]