# Unicorns and cruelty to animals

Tags: discussion, fun, unicorns, april-fools

I am really concerned about the unicorns i see in the site. 
Considering those extra shiny eyes or the hanging tongue, it seems that maybe some dope or drugs have been administrated to them, probably to try some substances out or to make them look happier.

[image]

I'm against cruelty to animals so please i will be glad if you can state that no animals were harmed during the development of the site.

Answer (score 21):

There was no cruelty to unicorns.

The featured unicorn has just hit his 1000 Unicoin - after a 52 hour clicking spree.

Both the accomplishment and tiredness are reflected in his tongue hanging out of his mouth and the shiny eyes.

Doing this was his idea, BTW. We didn't ask him to go through that nor do we endorse others to do so.

Answer (score 14):

As Oded said the unicorn is just really happy and tired, if a unicorn would do drugs it would look more like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9V8sr.gif

(Warning flashing image)

Comment: Alcohol **and** magic mushrooms. Never a good combo.

Comment: Tempted to flag as abusive (to my eyes).

Comment: @michaelb958 You might want to invest in [these special unicorn glasses](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227506/218170) then.

Comment: That, sir, is a work of art.

Answer (score 6):

No animals were harmed during the development of the site. In production, however…